# Should my book have considered $\mathbb{R}-\{1/3\}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: group-theory

In my book, I have a question saying

"Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ with the following operation
$$x\times y=x+y-3xy$$
is an (abelian) group."

Just like this. My point is that in order to compute the identity element $e$, I wrote

$$x\times e =x \Rightarrow x+y-3xy=x \Rightarrow e=\frac{0}{1-3x}.$$

Should my book have considered $\mathbb{R}-\{1/3\}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your reasoning is good, until the last step. You have $e(1-3x) = 0$ for all $x,$ and from here you should conclude  that $e$ should be zero.

Comment: But if I try to compute $x\times 1/3$, I will obtain $0/0$, right? Isn't it a issue?

Comment: Note that $x \times \frac{1}{3}$ is just $ x+ \frac{1}{3} - 3x\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$ so no trouble, and no $0/0.$

Comment: Oh... You are right, I should have written "the inverse of 1/3"

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. Also, which book are you referring to? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I do trust by the way, that you did show the associative property, and that you observed that the group is indeed abelian too, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation should be

$x\times e =x \Rightarrow x+e-3xe=x \Rightarrow e=0.$

Then the inverse of an element $x$ is given by $\frac {x}{3x-1}$ which works for all $x\ne \frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Your objection is somewhat correct:
For $x,e\in\mathbb R$ you have $x\times e=x\iff e(1-3x)=0\iff e=0\lor x=\frac 13$.

From this you can see that $(\mathbb R,\times)$ cannot be a group:
$\frac 13\times 0=\frac 1 3\times\frac 1 3$, so applying the inverse of $\frac 13 $ from the left would yield $0=\frac 13$.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** The only idempotent of a group $G$ is the identity $e$.

*Proof:* Let $x^2=x\in G$. Then $xx=x=xe$ so, multiplying by $x^{-1}$ on the left, we get $x=e$. $\square$

Suppose $r\in \Bbb R$ such that $r\times r=r$. Then $r=r+r-3r^2$ implies

$$\begin{align}
0&=r-3r^2\\
&=r(1-3r).
\end{align}$$

Thus either $r=0$ or $r=\frac{1}{3}$. We cannot have both, by the Lemma, if we are to have $(\Bbb R,\times)$ be a group. Indeed $0$ is an identity (as one can check easily).

But what about $r=\frac{1}{3}$? Well, for arbitrary $x\in\Bbb R$, if $x\times \frac{1}{3}=x$, then $x+\frac{1}{3}-x=x$ implies $x=\frac{1}{3}$, a contradiction (by letting,
say, $x=1$); thus we must indeed remove $\frac{1}{3}$.